# Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

Little by little I began to study React. Faced a stupid problem, I do not know how to solve it.
How to make my code work?
Now it’s clear that `const About` is also added via the `DOM`, and the `tick()` function cannot detect `div`.

about.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

const About = () => (
    <div>
        <div id="lol">
            <h1>AHJAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHAH</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="asd">
            asdasd
        </div>
    </div>
);

function tick() {
    const element = (
        <div>
            <h2>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
        </div>
    );
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('lol'));
}

tick();
setInterval(tick, 1000);


export default About;
```

Error line:

> ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('lol'));

Comment: The element "lol" must be in your html file

Comment: Has the div been added to the DOM already when calling the tick function the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to target the div `#lol` in the About function, but the only code you're processing with React is the code in the `tick()` function, and everything else is being ignored. The target element in the `React.render()` function should be in public/index.html.

`index.html`

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <div id="lol"></div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
        <h2>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
    </div>
  );

  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('lol'));
}

tick();
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Comment: This is clear. But I'm trying to make a multi-page site. And by clicking /about the same div #lol in root should be rendered.
Example https://furyclans.playrust.ru/, clicking on the button opens other tabs with internal functionality.

Comment: React.render() should be used once in your main file - e.g. index.js, and then the ticker should be a separate component you include on every page.
Read through https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html step by step, and it should make more sense :)

Comment: Оh, why php with web sockets is much easier than all this))
Thank you, I’ll go further into depression due to a poor understanding of this framework))

Comment: Ahaha, don't worry you will be fine, I come from a PHP background and I'm relatively new to this whole JavaScript framework world - you'll pick it up faster than you think. Good luck!